# Visual Studio 2022 "enable .net framework source" option missing

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I'm following the instructions from MS on how to enable debugging .net framework source here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2022

Debug->Options does not have a "enable .net framework source" option.

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.2

[image]

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that the "Enable Just My Code" option has inherited the option, but I can't find any concrete source saying so. I think you'd still have to make sure you have the symbols downloaded from Microsofts symbol server, but after configuring that, i wonder if you'll then be able to debug into the framework code.

Comment: This should be an issue, I suggest you to back to the previous version and report the situation to VS community. I also provide a way to avoid this issue, see my answer. :)

Comment: Submitted regression in UserVoice https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-enable-net-framewor/10396521

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Enable-NET-Framework-source-stepping/10372238?q=%22enable+.net+framework+source+stepping%22

Answer (score 3):

They [updated the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2022#enable-stepping-into-net-framework-source) on how to enable source debugging:

The important new step is 2.

> 2. Under Tools (or Debug) > Options > Debugging > Symbols, select Microsoft Symbol Servers.

After following those steps it should work in VS 17.6+.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my side and I am able to reproduce the same situation:

[image]

I also checked the release note of the VS2022 and it looks like no updates related to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1762--visual-studio-2022-version-1762

Here is a solution that can help you avoid this situation:

Go to [VS2022 release history of enterprise and professional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#fixed-version-bootstrappers)

**Download 17.5.4 instead:**

[image]

**I tested and this version has the section you required:**

[image]

If you want 17.6 version to have this section, I suggest you report issue here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest?

Comment: Submitted regression in UserVoice https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-enable-net-framewor/10396521